# Angular 2 go to default page if there is a 404 not found (don't exist url page)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

```
ngOnInit() {   
this.url = require('./red/file.html');
}
```

if that file it doesn't exist (and there is a 404 not found by browser) how do to load a default page for example *default.html* *?*

Answer (score 0):

add this in your routes config:

```
{path: '**', component: defaultComponent}
```

if the URL doesn’t match any of the other routes it will match this default route

Comment: Thanks, but i want load a default file, without use routes.

Comment: This is the way to do it.  Put your 404 html in defaultComponent and if a route is not found, it will load that.  Make sure to put it last in your route list.  Angular is a single page app, so you just inject views into a single file (index.html for example).  I guess you could redirect the user to a default.html, but I don't really see the point of that.

Comment: yes use default.html as a template for your component: "@Component({
  selector: 'default-app',
  templateUrl: './default.html'
})"